# MetaMask Gas Estimation Error in Staking dApp: "We were not able to estimate gas" without Sufficient Native Tokens. Big gas fee

Tags: web3js, metamask, gas, gas-estimate

I'm developing a staking dApp and have encountered a peculiar issue with MetaMask when attempting to execute transactions without sufficient native tokens in the wallet. MetaMask displays the error message: "We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail."(second image) Additionally, it estimates an impractically high gas fee around $2500 for the transaction. This issue does not manifest in another staking dApp like Uniswap (second image), where, under similar conditions (insufficient native tokens), the gas fee is reasonably calculated around $25 without any error messages.

Here are the details of the problem:

The error message and high gas fee estimate occur exclusively when there's an insufficient amount of native tokens in the wallet. The issue does not appear in other dApps that facilitate staking, where gas fees are calculated normally despite insufficient native tokens. Upon testing the transaction on Tenderly, no problems are detected, suggesting that the smart contract should execute as expected.

I'm trying to pinpoint the cause of this discrepancy and determine the appropriate area to investigate for a solution—whether the issue lies within the front end, the smart contracts, or MetaMask's gas estimation process under specific conditions. The primary goal is to resolve the error message and ensure MetaMask accurately calculates the gas fee for transactions in my staking dApp.

Would appreciate any insights into the cause of this issue and guidance on potential fixes or areas to investigate.

[image: MetaMask modals]